# navigation bar comes from top on tabaleview scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm facing a very weird issue, when I scroll down then the navigation bar comes from top and when I scrolls up then it goes up angain.

I have already a code to hide navigation bar, but still its comes

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
```

check video for reference
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AAyIjzx6AT07y1h_tMICOhgXxI3sWNvu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you provide more context? Is it UIKit? SwiftUI? Maybe provide the source code?

Answer (score 0):

try implement this line of code:

```
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```